# Is "foot to" an established, idiomatic phrase?

Tags: meaning, phrases

During my recent research I came across a document containing this line"

> Hopefully all of my entries **foot to** the 4 attachments a lot better than the version I sent you on Friday. ([original pdf from the SEC](https://www.sec.gov/news/studies/2009/oig-509/exhibit-0285.pdf))

I would've said "add to" which seems to be what the author intended the phrase to mean. "Foot" as a verb doesn't seem to have meanings along the lines of "add" "supplement", as per various dictionaries (W-M, Cambridge, to list a few that I have checked). Is it finance jargon?

Comment: What page of your link is the extract from?

Comment: It's established practice to [convert a noun into a verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria) meaning to act as that thing, to equip with that thing, to use that thing, etc, a practice often called "verbing". It's not entirely clear what this example actually means: what the relationship is between the entries and the attachments. I'd guess it's a nonce example of verbing rather than industry-specific jargon (although it might be a term that's gained currency in a specific workplace), but you could research that by looking for other occurrences. OTOH it might be a typo/thinko for "fit".

Comment: @user66974: It's on the very first page, in the paragraph numbered '3'.

Comment: The word "foot" certainly does have a meaning in accounting that is [total a column of figures](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/footing-accounting-66583.html). I think that is the usage here - it's saying "I hope my entries (in the report) add up to the expected values (in the attachments)". But you seem to have rejected fev's answer saying basically that?

Comment: Love the question, and *foot* is not finance talk. The writer could be making mistakes, like a mixed metaphor: "sticking their head up [neck out?] and saying the emperor isn't wearing any clothes but...." Chutzpah: "Very few people in the world have the mathematical background ... but I am one of them."

Comment: There are some useful comments here.  My advice is to read the four attachments, look at the document and see what evidence of 'foot to' might signify.

Comment: Perhaps this is intended to mean 'amount to' or 'equate to', but I feel 'correspond to the content of' is far better, and [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/foot)'s << **foot** [verb] ... [3]. To add up (a column of numbers) and write the sum at the bottom; total: footed up the bill. >> uses 'foot up to' rather than 'foot to', and stipulates the arithmetic domain.

Comment: I think this refers to footnotes that reference (link to) documents. One hopes that the footnote links to the right doc.

Comment: @psmears That answerer was apparently confused about the meaning of "foot the bill". They took two different dictionary entries and Frankensteined them together, mistakenly thinking they were the same thing, which, had they known the idiomatic phrase "foot the bill", would not have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is a typo for **fit**:

> Hopefully all of my entries **fit** to the 4 attachments a lot better than the version I sent you on Friday.

The message seems to be that the entries are more consistent or concordant with the attachments in this version than they were in the previous version. This use of "fit" as a verb is rather awkward and perhaps nonstandard but seems sensible to me.

Comment: Not buying that.

Comment: I don't think it would be "fit *to*" but simply "fit", judging from the author's style and register.  I don't think it is a typo either.  "fit the attachments a lot better" is what she would have written if **fit** had been the verb she had in mind.